# Carrierwave image upload returning empty at params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, file-upload, carrierwave

I'm pretty new to Rails and Carrierwave.

I have this form which displays a jquery modal box with some dynamic code to display 1 to N images chosen by the user when clicking the file button.

[image]

This is my input file, along with its form (I've removed the rest of html as it seems irrelevant for this purpose of illustrating my problem ):

```
<%= simple_form_for [:project, ConsolidatedDocument.new], html: { role: 'form' } do |f| %>
...
<input type="file" name="photo[files][]" multiple="multiple" id="file_upload_input">
...
<%= f.button :button, class: 'btn btn-primary btn-xs' %>
...
<% end %>
```

At my controller, I'm trying to save all the form inputs' values which seemingly automatically comes when hitting the button.

The trouble is that whatever value that should be coming with the input file is completely empty, and I cannot seem to find the reason why it's empty. Here's my params when hitting submit:

```
(byebug) params
{"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"xESj3za30Y9CBXqG6P3MHm9axNGsRY/+ejsiMLYfIPVyto7CAnTVYdhW5xBMlzpiBKPbXq2h0tfE8KYnXtmkVg==", "photo"=>{"files"=>[""]}, "macro_types_1"=>{"id"=>"4"}, "doc_types_create_1"=>{"id"=>"127"}, "macro_types_0"=>{"id"=>"5"}, "doc_types_create_0"=>{"id"=>"141"}, "document_checklist_comment"=>{"photo_ids"=>["87611", "87612"]}, "button"=>"", "controller"=>"consolidated_documents", "action"=>"create", "project_id"=>"524"}
```

See that "photo"=>{"files"=>[""]} insists in coming empty. As said, I'm not experienced with Rails and although I have searched through stackoverflow for similar problems, mine seems to be different than the ones I looked for here.

Any suggestions?

Edit:

As an update, I have tinkered with my form, by manually passing the file when I call ConsolidatedDocuments.new, like so:

```
post_attributes = params.require(:consolidated_document).permit(:name, :file, :document_type_id, :project_id, :user_id)
                @consolidated_document = ConsolidatedDocument.new("name" => @file_name, "file" => @file_string, "document_type_id" => params["doc_types_create_"+i.to_s]["id"],"project_id" => @project.id, "user_id" => current_user.id)
```

Then I have noticed that no matter what I pass as value for that "file" => @file_string part, it will always render "file"  as nil.

Here's how my object looks like at the time of hitting save:

```
(byebug) @consolidated_document
#<ConsolidatedDocument id: nil, name: "4f70d1b892066f849ee88222b7251ac6.jpg", file: nil, deleted: false, deleted_at: nil, document_type_id: 141, project_id: 524, user_id: 409, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```

file insists in comming out nil! How come?

Comment: Have you followed https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave#multiple-file-uploads

Comment: Yes @sajan. It's not the first image upload routine built in that system. So, all the parametrization and configurations have already been properly set. It seems to me that the nature of both this multifile upload and the fact that it contains some dynamically created inputs is the source of mess for this implementation. I'm trying to take a close look at it right now.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have the problem with simple_form_for.Try,

```
 **<%= simple_form_for :project, url: url_for(controller: "consolidated_documents", action: "create"), html: { role: 'form' } do |f| %>
...
<input type="file" name="photo[files][]" multiple="multiple" id="file_upload_input">
...
<% end %>**
```

Also **browse input** is not associated with the form and hence params appears only if any files exist at the time submission. Your button field is not linked with file input. Could be better if a full code of form is avaliable

Comment: Thanks @Sathishkumar Jayaraj! That's what I was looking for!

Comment: @ClaudioFernandoMaciel please provide tick for the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

Change the form like below:

```
<%= form_for(@consolidated_document) do |f| %>

<%= file_field_tag "photo[]", multiple: true  %>

<%= f.submit %>
```

In controller new:

```
@consolidated_document = ConsolidatedDocument.new
```